# Set margins of view xcode

Tags: xcode, uiview, margin

I have been programming android apps for a bit, and I am now making an iphone app.  I want to make margins for my view.  I would not like to explain my exact situation, but if someone helps me with this I'll be able to figure out what I need to do.

I have two views, I want the first view to take up the entire screen.  Then I want another view to always be, lets say 20 pixels from the edge of the screen on all four sides.  Is there a simple way to do that in xcode?

Thanks

Comment: In Xcode? Or rather in your app, I guess? (If the latter, then this is **not related** to Xcode, since you can make iOS apps without Xcode - please read Xcode's tag wiki.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using Interface Builder (now part of Xcode).

Add the view as you suggest - leaving a 20 pixel border around all 4 sides. Set all 6 resize options (flexible height, width, top, bottom, left & right).

[image]

Ensure that 'autoresize subviews' is enabled on the parent view.

The view will now resize if the parent view also resizes, leaving a 20px margin as required.